# Three.js Coordinate system confusing

Tags: three.js, raycasting, euler-angles

I have a basic question regarding coordinate system in Three.js. I have a spherical geometry of radius 500 and a camera placed at (0,0,0). I am using raycasting to find the intersection on the spherical surface. I can see in the intersect object that the **distance** is always 500 , but the z coordinate in **point** variable is not constant. As per my understanding z-coordinate represents the depth and since the camera is at origin the z-coordinate should also be 500.  Any help or link would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is really hard to read. Can you put the code to jsfiddle?

Comment: Think about this: A sphere of radius 500 means that all points on the sphere are 500 distance units away from it. That doesn't mean all z coordinates will be 500 though. From your depth argument, think about a semicircle in front of you. Some parts are closer and some are further, i.e. the depth changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the image - both of `a` and `b` has the same length (suppose 500 in your case). But clearly, the intersection points have different `z` coordinate.

[image]